# texts still filtering with Error: 30035 despite US A2P 10DLC sole proprietor brand, campaign and messaging service verification

Tags: ruby, twilio, sms

Texts from my Ruby on Rails app sent out with Twilio keep getting filtered.  My tiny app sends out around 50 texts a night with scheduling information.  I registered my sole proprietor on the Twilio site brand in May, 2023.  I have a verified campaign and messaging service and only 1 number sending out messages.  When I use the code at https://console.twilio.com/us1/develop/sms/try-it-out/send-an-sms to test the filtering between 15% and 25% get blocked.  Anyone have any ideas?

My test code is:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'twilio-ruby'

account_sid = ENV['TWILIO_ACCOUNT_SID']
auth_token = ENV['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']
@client = Twilio::REST::Client.new(account_sid, auth_token)

n=0
20.times do
  message = @client.messages.create(
    #body: "number test from #{n}",
    body: "messaging service test from #{n}",
    messaging_service_sid: ENV['MESSAGING_SERVICE_SID'],
    #from: ENV['TWILIO_APP_NUMBER'],
    to: ENV['MY_CELL_NUMBER']
    )

    puts message.sid
    n+=1
end
```

3 to 5 of the 20 test messages (15-25%) get blocked with the `(Error: 30035) US A2P 10DLC - Message from a number still being configured` error.

Thanks so much in advance if you have any thoughts for this amateur.

Answer (score 1):

Twilio support just got back to me and it turns out I needed to remove my number from the messaging service and add it back again.  Instructions found at https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/4402705042075-Managing-a-Messaging-Service-Sender-Pool

Had to turn my messaging service off and turn it on again!